# can we check the validation of uitextfield while Unit Testing?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest

Suppose we have some validation in our `ViewController` ( say vc1 ) for a `UItextfield` in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method, as user only can enter the numbers not the alphabets or other special character.

I just want to know that in our `XCTestCase` class, is this possible in unit testing, to check for a particular `uitextfield`, is allowing some characters (in my case only numbers) or not?

Answer (score 7):

Make unit tests that call `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` and check the expectation that the result should be true, or false.

This is an example of how to unit test delegate methods. Where UIKit invokes a particular method, just have tests call the same thing.

Even though a particular class may implement the delegate method, it's better if the test remains ignorant of this. UIKit asks the text field for its delegate, then calls it. Our tests should do the same, and invoke through the delegate. Otherwise we are locking down the implementation, which would make it harder to refactor the delegate methods.

```
func testMyTextField_ShouldAllowAlphabeticCharacters() {
    let vc = // …Whatever you do to load your view controller
    vc.loadViewIfNeeded() // Make sure text field is loaded
    let field = vc.myTextField

    // Call through field.delegate, not through vc
    let result = field.delegate.textField(field,
                         shouldChangeCharactersIn: NSMakeRange(0, 1),
                         replacementString: "a")

    XCTAssertTrue(result)
}
```

Comment: Jon, this approach seems to work for most of the cases. Do you have any idea how to test logic for markedText?. For example I have this `if textField.markedTextRange != nil { <code here is never called> } `

Comment: @nacho4d I've never dealt with marked text. I presume something in your production code is calling `setMarkedText(_:selectedRange:replacementRange:)`? And have you confirmed whether this production code is being triggered by a test?

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is no unit test, but UI testing, because the behavior of your UI is no unit. But there is the ability to include UI testing in your tests, which will participate on the test chain.

Basically you get the UI element (`XCUIElement`) you want to test and send actions to it, i. e. using `-typeText:`. Then you compare the actual state of that element to the intended state using the `XCUIElementAttributes` protocol.

Googling for the above identifiers will give you some details. However, the documentation is not that good.