# XCTest unable to find textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xctest

I am learning XCTest framework. I want to test whether the textfield accepts numeric values or not [which it should not]. But XCTest is unable to find the textfield.

```
XCUIApplication().textFields["name"].typeText("123")
XCTAssertEqual(XCUIApplication().textFields["name"].title, "")
```

`name` is palceholder of textfield. I have only one textfield in this demo app. But test always fails on 1st line of test code and no error is shown.

> Note:  I have made the appropriate code for not letting the textfield
>   accept numeric values.

Comment: You can accomplish this with a unit test instead of a UI test: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47419707/246895

Answer (score 1):

If you want to examine an element, first step is to check whether it is accessible by an identifier or not. The crash happens because the system can not find the text field named "name".

You have to set an identifier to that text field.

```
yourTextField.accessibilityIdentifier = "myTextField"
```

Now, you can get the textfield by the string "myTextField"

```
XCUIApplication().textFields["myTextField"]
```

Use Voice over/Accessibility inspector to check elements labels/values/identifiers.